# How to combine 2 mysql AVG query?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql. I was trying to figure out how to get the avg of avg but didnt work. So I need some help.

I have a table with date column and price column.

I would like to get only one number, the avg of the avg price on each day.

clear that I need the average of the prices group by date, but I have tried many times with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to use a subquery:

```
select avg(avgp)
from (select date, avg(price) as avgp
      from table_t
      group by date
     ) dp;
```

The sub-query returns the partial averages as a new table (dp) with a column (avgp), and the global average is computed in the outer query.

Comment: hello thanks the quick answer. i havent tested yet, but my question is what is that DP at the and? I understand the rest mor or less. :)

Comment: @ZoOolcsi try it without the dp